# jQuery – How to target specific instances of a class on scroll

Tags: jquery, animation, scroll

I'm relatively new to jQuery so forgive me if there's an obvious solution here.

**What I'm trying to accomplish:** as the user scrolls through the page, content will animate in via the removal of CSS classes.

**The problem:** I would like to only target instances of a class inside the current viewport. ***Currently, the animation is affecting all instances of a class (once the first instance of the class is scrolled to).*** I'm not able to hard-code unique classes for each element since I'd like the admin of the site to be able to add as many of those elements as they'd like.

Here's what I have so far:

```
// CHECKS IF ELEMENT IS IN VIEWPORT
$.fn.isInViewport = function () {
    var l_scroll = $(window).scrollTop(); // how many pixels you've scrolled
    var l_os = $('.product-bp-left').offset().top; // pixels to the top of div
    var l_ht = $('.product-bp-left').height(); // height of div in pixels
    var w_ht = $(window).height(); // height of window

    return l_scroll > l_os - w_ht + l_ht;
}

$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($('.product-bp-left').isInViewport()) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $('.product-bp-left').find('.product-bp-img').removeClass('product-fade-right-anim');
        }, 450);
        setTimeout(function () {
            $('.product-bp-left').find('.product-bp-gutter').removeClass('product-fade-right-anim');
        }, 550);
        setTimeout(function () {
            $('.product-bp-left').find('.product-bp-text').removeClass('product-fade-anim');
        }, 1200);
    } else {

    }
});
```

I've tried using the "this" selector but it doesn't seem to work with "if" statements – or at least not how I'm expecting it to. I'd appreciate any insight!

Answer (score 0):

Was able to get this working with help from my Head of Web and some further searching – need to use "each" and also call "this" from outside the "setTimeout." Working code below, hope it helps any future searchers.

```
// CHECKS IF ELEMENT IS IN VIEWPORT
$.fn.isInViewport = function () {
    var l_scroll = $(window).scrollTop(); // how many pixels you've scrolled
    var l_os = $(this).offset().top; // pixels to the top of div
    var l_ht = $(this).height(); // height of div in pixels
    var w_ht = $(window).height(); // height of window

    return l_scroll > l_os - w_ht + l_ht;
}

$(window).scroll(function () { 
    $('.product-bp-left').each(function () {
    if ($(this).isInViewport()) {
        var bp_left = $(this);
        setTimeout(function () {
            $(bp_left).find('.product-bp-img').removeClass('product-fade-right-anim');
        }, 450);
        setTimeout(function () {
            $(bp_left).find('.product-bp-gutter').removeClass('product-fade-right-anim');
        }, 550);
        setTimeout(function () {
            $(bp_left).find('.product-bp-text').removeClass('product-fade-anim');
        }, 1200);
    } else {

    }
});
});
```